# Show $(x^{kp})^{1/kq} = (x^p)^{1/q}$

Tags: analysis, functions

Show for $x>0$ and $ p, q \in \mathbb N$ that $$(x^{kp})^{1/(kq)} = (x^p)^{1/q}$$ given $(x^p)^{1/q} = (x^{1/q})^p$.

Perhaps use injectivity of $f(x)=x^{kp}$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $x$ is what?  $p$ is what?  $q$ is what?  $k$ is what?  Also, $1/kq$ means $1/(kq)$ and not $(1/k)q$, right?

Comment: x is a real greater than zero, p,q are natural numbers, and 1/kq=1/(kq)

Comment: 4 out or 5 explanations provided.  How about putting them in the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

Usually exponents of arbitrary base are defined as$$x^k=e^{k\ln x}.$$ Therefore $$(x^{kp})^{1/kq}=(e^{kp\ln x})^{1/kp}=e^{\frac{1}{kq}\ln (e^{kp\ln x})}.$$ We know that $$e^{\ln x}=x.$$ I think now you can continue form here. Also I found a [similar question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009996/real-analysis-of-powers)